# Android open UTF-8 XML

Tags: android, utf-8

Hello I get some xml file
They are on UTF-8 so i follow some sample and my code look like this

```
String text = "";   
String str;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(Path), "UTF-8"));
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    text += str;
}
return text;
```

And then i try to parse the code with the dom parser

```
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(result);
```

And this fail
I have check my xml file with a hexeditor
I have the following charcode before "<": ef bb bf

What have i miss? why getDomElement tell me 
    Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text += str + "\n";
```

If there was a line break in a tag:

```
<img
src="smile.jpg"/>
```

you could get:

```
<imgsrc="smile.jpg">
```

And some other cases.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();   
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(Path), "UTF-8"))) {
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(str).append("\n");
    }
} // Does an in.close()
return text.toString();
```

Comment: Actually i have try something else i don't know if your method work but it seem better than my first try

Comment: The error being that `readLine` strips the newline char(s) `\r`, `\n`, `NEL`; so we need to add them again ourselves.

Comment: I have solve mine bug by change my documentbuilder like this

    InputSource src = new InputSource(stream);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();